# Binding the Images to Image Tag from PhotoChooserTask in ListBox with Same Size in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone

I am working on windows phone 7.

i have to bind the images selected from PhotoChooserTask in a ListBox like Tiles in Windows Phone 7.

I have a design file like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstImages" Height="530" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource PickerBoxButton}" 
                                x:Name="btnDashboardItems"
                                Tag="{Binding Name}" 
                                Padding="0" Margin="-18,0,-12,-45" Height="200"
                                Width="200">                                    
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Height="173" Width="173">
                                                <Image Height="173" Width="173"
                                                       Source="{Binding Image}" /> 
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="450" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
```

and i have a class called ImageList like this:

```
public class ImageList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and I am binding to the listbox like this:

```
PhotoChooserTask task = new PhotoChooserTask();
task.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(task_Completed);
task.Show();
```

**Here i can select any No of Images So i have taken the ListBox.**

```
Random _Random = new Random();
 private void task_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
             {
                System.IO.Stream stream = e.ChosenPhoto;
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                bmp.SetSource(stream);
                img.Image = bmp;
                img.Name = _Random.Next(int.MaxValue).ToString() + ".jpg";
                StateUtilities.ImageList.Add(img);  
                if (StateUtilities.ImageList != null)
               {
                   if (StateUtilities.ImageList.Count > 0)
                   {
                      lstImages.ItemsSource = StateUtilities.ImageList;
                   }
               }    
             }
        }
```

**Here i am able bind the images but images are coming at different sizes but i have given fixed size(Height and Width) to button and Image Tag, still I am getting the images in Different Sizes (Different Height and Width) .
How can i make that images bind at Same Size?**

Thanks,

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

I think that the StackPanel will stretch according to the content.

Have you tried setting MaxWidth and MaxHeight too?